# jquery how to check near element with certain class exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, closest

I have two element inside `<tr>`:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-state" onclick="myfunction(this)"></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-city" onclick="myfunction(this)"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

in the `myfunction` I want to check if element with cartain class exist or not:

```
if($(thisElem).closest("tr").find(".input-city").length){
    console.log('true')
 }
```

but `$(thisElem).closest("tr").find(".input-city").length` is always `0` !
how do I check this element existance?

Comment: Work fine for me, but if you want to know fi the element you click has a specific class use `$(thisElem).hasClass("input-city")`

Comment: yes but the problem comes with your html. wrap those tr inside a regular table and that length will return 1

Comment: @DiegoDeVita you are almost right, it's about wraping! I wrap the `let a = $(thisElem).closest("tr").find(".input-city")` and then `$(a).lenght return 1 .

Comment: @aref razavi I posted an answer showing exactly my point. Your suggestion is pretty redundant and anyway it's length and not lenght

Answer (score 0):

This is to show that the problem is due to the invalid html since tr should be wrapped inside a table like this demo shows:

```js
function myfunction(target){
  if($(target).closest("tr").find(".input-city").length){
    console.log('true');
  }else{
    console.log('false');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Working</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-state" onclick="myfunction(this)"></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-city" onclick="myfunction(this)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h1>Not Working</h1>

<tr>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-state" onclick="myfunction(this)"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-city" onclick="myfunction(this)"></td>
</tr>
```